# Need to create a Dictionary <int, List<string>> using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have following file names in my files folder

```
1000_A.csv
1000_B.csv
1000_C.csv
1001_A.csv
1001_B.csv
```

files names starting with same ID needs to be added to a list and then the list needs    to added to a dictionary with ID as key

For ex:
    list x contains "1000_A.csv", "1000_B.csv", "1000_C.csv"
   add this to a dictionary  with ID 1000 as the key  Please help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @danrhul yet you gave him an answer! :)

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I'm just a nice guy and I'm pretty sure he is a she

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ`'s `GroupBy`:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> idFilenames = fileList
    .Select(fileName =>
    {
        string fnwoe = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        string idPart = fnwoe.Split('_').First();
        int id;
        int.TryParse(idPart, out id);
        return new { fileName, id };
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.fileName).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var folder = GetFolder();
var files = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

foreach (var file in folders) 
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(file.Substring(0, file.IndexOf('_'));

    if (files.Any(x => x.Key == id))
        files[id].Add(file);
    else 
    {
        var newList = new List<string>(); 
        newList.Add(file);

        files.Add(id, newList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfFiles = ...; // assuming you can read the list of filenames 
                       //  into a string[] or IList<string>

var d = listOfFiles.GroupBy( f => f.Substring( 0, f.IndexOf( '_' ) ) )
    .ToDictionary( g => g.Key, g => g );
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g CSV the list of your csv files

Loop through you CSV list:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> files = new List<string>();
foreach (string path CSV)
{
     if(!ContainsKey(path.Substring(0,3))
       {
         files.Add(path);
         Dict.Add(path.Substring(0,3),files);
       }
     else
      {
       files.Add(path);
       Dict[path.Substring(0,3)].Add(file);
      }
  }
```